# How can I fix role.setPermissions function error?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to change the permissions of a role, but I keep getting an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPermissions' of undefined`. As far as I can tell, all of my syntax and logic are fine:

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "name");
role.setPermissions(["SEND_MESSAGES"])
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check & ensure that `role` is not undefined.

If `role` were a proper role object, this should go all as initially planned given you're using the appropriate version of `discord.js`.

Regarding reasons why `role` would be undefined, it seems there was a failure in finding a role that has a `name` property equal to `"name"`.

Comment: I believe it is defined corectly. I had the exact syntax for defining it before I got this error. I think the error is from the syntax of the `setPermisions` function.

Comment: It looks according to what is demonstrated on the official guide. Judge with the semantics of the message. "Cannot read property [x] *of undefined*" tells us the object is undefined, just as you would tell someone to "Get the height property OF Rectangle", for example.